# Select unique value's of two different columns from duplicate rows in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Table 1

```
school_Name Student_Name Class_ID    
AMM          joe         AMM-1-1-1
AMM          joe         AMM-1-1-2
AMM          Adam        AMM-1-1-1
AMM          Adam        AMM-1-1-2
AMM          Nancy       AMM-1-2-1
AMM          Nancy       AMM-1-2-2
AMM          Albert      AMM-1-2-1
AMM          Albert      AMM-1-2-2
IRB          Frank       IRB-1-1-1
IRB          Frank       IRB-1-1-2
IRB          Mike        IRB-1-1-1
IRB          Mike        IRB-1-1-2
```

Hello, I have above similar table in oracle and trying to select unique class_id (1st) for 1st match of student name in that school. could anyone pls help.

The expected output of select statment as follow:

Result

```
school_Name Student_Name Class_ID    
AMM          joe         AMM-1-1-1
AMM          Adam        AMM-1-1-2
AMM          Nancy       AMM-1-2-1
AMM          Albert      AMM-1-2-2
IRB          Frank       IRB-1-1-1
IRB          Mike        IRB-1-1-2
```

Tried below but still not working as expected.

```
select 
  school_name,
  student_name,
  class_id, 
from 
(
  select
    school_name,
    student_name,
    class_id,
    row_number() over (partition by class_id order by student_name ASC) rn
  from studentdata_view
) where rn = 1;
```

Comment: What does "not working as expected" mean? You got a wrong result? No result? An error message? Headaches?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? MySQL or Oracle? These are different products.

Comment: "not working as expected" - Your expectation is not clear. Do you expect the `Student_Name` **and** `Class_ID` to be independently unique?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your partition by clause, removed the extra comma before 1st from also

```
select school_name,student_name,class_id from 
(
   select school_name,student_name,class_id, row_number() over (partition by 
   school_name,student_name order by class_id ASC) rn from studentdata_view
)A where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a comma too many in your query:

```
select 
  school_name,
  student_name,
  class_id -- <=== it was here; I removed it 
from 
(
  select
    school_name,
    student_name,
    class_id,
    row_number() over (partition by class_id order by student_name ASC) rn
  from studentdata_view
) where rn = 1;
```

I also changed `full_class_id` to `class_id`in your partition by clause.

Answer (score 0):

So you want each class appear only once in output? I think you need more complicated algorithm for that. Here is something what should work if there are only two persons "rivalizing" in each class, like in your example:

```
select * 
  from (
    select school_name,student_name, class_id, 
           dense_rank() over (partition by school_name, class_id order by student_name) rnk,
           count(distinct student_name) over (partition by school_name, class_id) cnt,
           row_number() over (partition by school_name, student_name order by class_id ) rn
      from studentdata_view)
  where cnt = 1 
     or (cnt = 2 and ((rnk = 1 and rn = 1) or (rnk = 2 and rn = 2)))
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=61570608af6e38ec05ef7e3bde69be5b)</sup>**

Result:

```
SCHOOL_NAME STUDENT_NAME CLASS_ID         RNK        CNT         RN
----------- ------------ --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
AMM         Adam         AMM-1-1-1          1          2          1
AMM         joe          AMM-1-1-2          2          2          2
AMM         Albert       AMM-1-2-1          1          2          1
AMM         Nancy        AMM-1-2-2          2          2          2
IRB         Frank        IRB-1-1-1          1          2          1
IRB         Mike         IRB-1-1-2          2          2          2
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the help. there might be more than two students "rivalizing" in each class " maximim can be 62 repetitions then yes each class should appear only once "student_name" and "class_id" should be unique none of these should be repeated in the output.